# In HTML5+CSS, is <nav class="nav"> redundant?

Tags: css, nav

In an online tutorial, I was recently told to create a class for nav elements called "nav". I'm a beginner in CSS, but is it just me, or is this redundant/confusing/bad practice?

Comment: In my opinion its not redundant, but in the end its up to the person writing the code how they want to manage styling. I personally like to make a class and use that instead

Comment: It all really depends on your html markup. If for some reason you have multiple `<nav>` elements, a class would be helpful. i don't think there is a right answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not redundant. The DOM element `nav` is different from the CSS class `nav`.

If you wanted to style this element by class, you would use this style declaration (for example):

```
.nav { background-color : #F00; }
```

if it were styled by element type it would be:

```
nav { background-color : #F00; }
```

This may seem trivial, but that period `.` makes a difference. It means you are identifying the item by class and not by element name. If you use the class syntax (with the `.`) then you could also write:

```
<div class="nav"></div>
```

This would show with a red background if you included the class definition, but not if you styled the element type directly.

In simple applications you may be able to get away with directly styling element types (e.g. `<nav>`) as opposed to classes (e.g. `class="nav"`), but as you get more complex layouts you are going to want to use classes. Additionally, if you use a selector-based library like jQuery, or `document.querySelect()` you may have good reasons for specifying a class.

If you truely can know that all `<nav>` elements can be styled the same in all your pages, then by all means just use the element selector, but to leave yourself flexibility it's best to use classes.

Comment: Great detailed description, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**NO** it's not redundant.

**YES** it's redundant *if* you think in your specific case you're fine with `nav{ /*blaah blaah*/ }`

`<nav>` is a Semantic HTML5 tag that represents toward SEO a *navigation*. A navitagion is all you want it to be. So in the case you have *multiple* `nav` elements in our page and you're OK to target-styles  directly the *tag* element using `nav` I'll be glad to see that.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Best practice says you really never should style the actual element. You should always use classes. This allows for future scale and better written CSS.

Comment: Good information about how the SEO treats `<nav>`, thanks.